# Passing parameters to __construct library in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, construct

I am really new to Codeigniter, and just learning from scratch. checked the documentation on `Creating Libraries` but no success on my example:

I need to pass a value to `__construct` library.

class: libraries/Myclasses/Bird

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Bird{
 public $fly;
 public $goodsound;

 public function __construct($fly, $goodsound) {
    $fly = $this->fly;
    $goodsound = $this->goodsound;
 }
 public function sentance(){
    return "This Bird can ".$this->fly . " and has ". $this->goodsound;
 }
}
```

class: libraries/Mybird

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/Myclasses/Bird.php');

class Mybird extends Bird {
  public function __construct() {
  }
}
```

controller: Birds

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Birds extends CI_Controller {
 public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $config = array('fly' => 'fly', 'goodsound' => 'very good');
    $this->load->library('Mybird', $config);
 }

 public function index(){
    $mybird = new mybird();
    echo $mybird->sentance();
 }
}
```

I think that the problem is in Mybird class that not passing the values but i can't figure out how to handle it.

Comment: why are you loading library Mybird twice in controller birds? Once with and once without $config???

Comment: it was just a try .. but for sure no success!

Comment: I think firstly your library Mybird also needs to be set to except parameters in its constructor when the library is called:

Comment: I tried to put them inside `parent::__construct();` I dont know if this is the correct way ... but when i do that I cant get the controller values! .. i really need who can correct me!

Comment: Just curious, what is the reason for needing to pass parameters to __construct()?

Comment: also don't extend your libray, make one only, if you call $this->load->library('Bird', $config); it should work

Comment: @Vickel I would like to do that but I need to extend to CI_Controller. this is my problem.

Comment: @Goose I need it because the In real library its bring data for json using this way!!!

Answer (score 2):

One issue is in the constructor for `Bird`. Try this.

```
class Bird{
    public $fly;
    public $goodsound;

    public function __construct($fly, $goodsound)
    {
        $this->fly = $fly;
        $this->goodsound = $goodsound;
    }
```

Without the `$this->` before the property name you are creating local variables that will go out of scope when the constructor ends.

Secondly, any class extending Bird should pass two arguments to the base class constructor. For instance:

```
class Mybird extends Bird {
  public function __construct() 
  {
      parent::__construct('Fly', 'very good');
  }
}
```

You could define `Mybird` to accept arguments too and then pass those to parent::__construct

```
class Mybird extends Bird {
  public function __construct($fly, $goodsound) 
  {
      parent::__construct($fly, $goodsound);
  }
}
```

There is no need for the `new` call in the Controller - `$this->load->library('Mybird', $config);` did that for you already.

`index()` should work fine as shown below. Note that `Mybird` is a property of the controller and so needs to be accessed using `$this`.

```
 public function index(){
    echo $this->Mybird->sentance();
 }
```

However, if you want to pass a `$config` array as an argument when loading a library then you need to revise both the `Bird` and the `Mybird` classes like so.

```
class Bird
{
    public $fly;
    public $goodsound;

    public function __construct($config)
    {
        $this->fly = $config['fly'];
        $this->goodsound = $config['goodsound'];
    }

}


class Mybird extends Bird
{
    public function __construct($config)
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your library `Mybird` also needs to be set to except parameters in its constructor when the library is called from the controller `Bird` with `$this->load->library('Mybird', $config);`

when extending the library, you need to stick to what is set in your config.php, something like `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';` would require MY_Bird instead of Mybird

more info on the subject [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html#passing-parameters-when-initializing-your-class) and [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html#setting-your-own-prefix)

Comment: I can call itself in the same class ? is it working? you mean like that? `class Mybird extends Bird {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->library('Mybird', $config);
    }
}`